# Handling common components with NPM on development

Tags: npm, ionic2, continuous-integration, soa

I have developed several reusable components for my ionic2 applications, among this I have security, fmcManagment, formsManagment among others, and new apps just reuse this components using NPM.

When I work ONLY on new apps reusing this modules, the model works perfectly and Im able to use the livereload functionalities which speed development, but when I need to make changes to the common components I totally lost this, due the fact that the code for components is not directly related to the new project, so for every change o common component, I need to stop the app, rebuild the module, reinstall using node then restart the app.

What I would like to achieve is to relate the components code on dev time, so when I make a change to the common component's code, the changes are picked up live, instead of doing all the manual process, but for deployment time I'll need to keep the standard npm libs structure, what should be the best way to achieve this escenario?

Comment: Im guessing that it should be about playing around with ionic build scripts, but I guess I should also update the components import, so in dev time, it points to a certain location, and on prod points to the right npm module, any ideas?